# Chromebook crouton LAMP

Tags: apache-httpd, mysql, php, chrome-book, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install a LAMP stack on Ubuntu through crouton on a Chromebook (Acer c720p).

I was able to install the following packages

```
apache2 mysql-client mysql-server php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

and the localhost folder works correctly. When I try to install phpmyadmin I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

The only way to exit from the sudo apt-get installation is to ignore the error. Then, if I go to localhost/phpmyadmin, phpmyadmin looks to work, but I cannot log in and I get

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

How do I configure MySQL so that phpmyadmin is able to connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

When installed, MySQL doesn't start by default, you have to start it.

```
service mysqld start
```

then run the security

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

also see : https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Running-servers-in-crouton